# echo of var to file in SConscript

Tags: scons

In an SConscript file I have a env variable `BUILDID_STR`
 that contains a C string that I wish to output to a file.

```
bstr = env['BUILDID_STR']
print(bstr)
```

which when printed, `print(bstr)` correctly shows this:

```
//this file is automatically generated
static char* build_str="0|0.1.0|2014-05-29_16:16:51";
```

However, I can't get the var expanded/exported correctly, just the literal string is output instead of the above text:

```
cat src/log/src/version.c
env[BUILDID_STR]
```

Here's the pertinent part of my SConscript file

```
env.Command(target='#/src/log/src/version.c',
        source=libSrcfiles,
        action="echo env['BUILDID_STR'] > $TARGET")


env.SharedLibrary('log', [libSrcfiles, '#/src/log/src/version.c'])
```

I've also tried the code in a function and also passing to a shell script, all with the same result.
The reason I have .../version.c in the SharedLibrary is that my goal is to have the .c file generated only when on of the `libSrcfiles` is built, thereby version.c is compiled-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen, the action is not expanding the env variable. In the action, you can refer to env variables with the `$VAR` syntax (just like referring to the `$SOURCE` and `$TARGET` variables provided by SCons):

```
env.Command(target='#/src/log/src/version.c',
    source=libSrcfiles,
    action="echo $BUILDID_STR > $TARGET")
```

This solution may not handle a `BUILDID_STR` containing multiple lines.

You may want to investigate a system that builds your source file from a template (instead of constructing the file contents entirely within a string). The [Substfile Builder](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#b-Substfile) referenced in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010320/how-can-i-get-scons-to-replace-text-in-installed-text-files) might be a good starting point -- you can provide a list of (key, value) pairs to be substituted in an input file. The Substfile Builder is built into recent versions of SCons.

Comment: I finally got action= above to work but I had to pass to a shell script instead of echo.  The quotes and pipes in the string were messing up the echo.  Thanks Dave.

Answer (score 3):

The "`textfile`" Tool offers two Builders `Textfile()` and `Substfile()` for cases like this. You probably want to use the first:

```
env = Environment(tools=['textfile'])
env['BUILDID_STR'] = 'A test'
env.Textfile('test.txt', ['$BUILDID_STR'])
```